# What is the fastest way to create an image from an array in PHP?

Tags: php, image

I want to create a large number of 256 x 256 PNG images in PHP from an array that includes the values for x and y as well as the colors: r, g, and b.

I've been doing this one pixel at a time using `imagesetpixel()`, but I'm wondering if there is a faster method?

I am using PHP 5.3.28.

Comment: Where's your code? Specifically, this array and what you're currently doing with it.

Comment: Also, PHP 5.3 is [EOL for almost two years](http://php.net/eol.php) now. Time to move up to 7.0!

Comment: It would be significantly faster if you used `C++` and `magick++` and used the `read()` function to read the images from your array - you could also multi-thread or multi-process to make things faster if you have a dual/quad core or more CPU.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about moving most of the project over to C++ for speed.